# Python Output to HTML

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to aggregate pieces from different websites and consolidate them into a single site.

Since the information will change daily, I was trying to output the HTML code dynamically with `%s` formatting. However, this seems ripe for disaster somewhere along the way as the amount of information grows since I don't know of any way I can label the `%s` to at least keep track of what they're referring to (This is only a fraction of what I would like to ultimately have).

I tried looking at Bootstrap, but it was a little beyond me honestly as all I'm looking to do is have a simple HTML output. Is that the best solution at this point?

```
url = 'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features = 'xml')

items = soup.findAll('item')
print(items)

all_items = ''

wrapper = """
<html>
   <header>
   Daily Monitor
   </header>
<body>
        <p>URL: <a href=\"%s\">%s</a></p>
        <p> %s </p>
</body>
</html>"""

x = wrapper % ('What', 'to', 'do')

#This is the data I would like to eventually incorporate into the HTML - not used here in the example
for item in items[:10]:
    all_items += item.title.text
    print(item.description.text)
    print(item.link)

#this is how I'm writing out the HTML
filename = 'C:\\test' + '.html'
f = open(filename,'w')
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the new style of string substitution, with [`.format()`](https://pyformat.info). It will allow you to have a much more readable template string.

Consider the following:

```
all_items = {
  'title': 'Google',
  'link': 'https://google.com',
  'description': 'Hey, have you heard about this new search engine?'
}

wrapper = """
<html>
   <header>
   Daily Monitor
   </header>
<body>
        <p>URL: <a href=\"{link}\">{title}</a></p>
        <p> {description} </p>
</body>
</html>"""

x = wrapper.format(**all_items)
```

And [here it is in action](https://repl.it/NSWO).

Comment: Nice one - Thanks. Going to mess around with this - I have a lot of sites so thinking how I can cleverly build the dictionary out as a loop - thanks!

Comment: No problem. I use `.format()` all the time, even for debug messages to myself.

Comment: Nice way to solve that problem. I added some CSS-code to my wrapper, but now the .format() identified the curly brackets as a key that should be replaced. Is there a way to escape needed curly brackets?